# Combine two streams into one to return a Pair

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of `Objects` consisting of only two fields. I want to convert it into `Pair` for easy access to fields for further process. In the following code, I am doing two `streams` to get the `Pair` and I intend to do it in a single stream.

What could be the best way to combine these two `streams`?

EDIT : I want Pair of list. `Pair<List<Long>, List<String>>`

```
List<Long> activeUserIds = activeUserIdAndTokenResults.stream().map(AppRegistrationRepository.ActiveUserIdAndTokenResult::getUserId).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> activeTokens = activeUserIdAndTokenResults.stream().map(AppRegistrationRepository.ActiveUserIdAndTokenResult::getToken).collect(Collectors.toList());
return Pair.of(activeUserIds, activeTokens);
```

For `Pair`, I have used `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple`

Comment: Do you need a `Pair<List<Long>,List<String>>` like you're doing now or a `List<Pair<Long, String>>`? If the latter, then just create the pair in the `map()` method: `activeUserIdAndTokenResults.stream().map(userIdAndToken -> Pair.of(userIdAndToken.getUserId(), userIdAndToken.getToken()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Thomas I think OP actually wants the pair of lists but wants to avoid streaming over the same collection twice.

Comment: If the idea is, as others have suggested, to return a stream/list of pairs, check out Guava's [`Streams.zip()`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.function.BiFunction)).

Comment: @shmosel yes, I assume so as well. I probably wouldn't do that though because it feels odd to split related information into separate collections and pair those collections again. Hence the question to understand if this is _really_ the goal and not just a failed attempt.

Comment: @Thomas, I need Pair<List<Long>, List<String>>

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you actually intend to return a pair of lists, you can use the Pair as your collector:

```
return activeUserIdAndTokenResults.stream().collect(
        () -> Pair.of(new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>()),
        (p, r) -> {
            p.getLeft().add(r.getUserId());
            p.getRight().add(r.getToken());
        },
        (p1, p2) -> {
            p1.getLeft().addAll(p2.getLeft());
            p2.getRight().addAll(p2.getRight());
        });
```

Just remember that streams are not always an improvement over old-fashioned loops.

Comment: I stand with you about the over-use of streams vs. good-ol' loops.